# Old buttons disappear when I add a new one

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have an iPhone App with a view which contains 2 buttons. I created these buttons in the Interface Builder.

Now I want to add a new button to the view programmatically:

```
- (void) addButton {
    //allocate the view
    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];

    //set the view's background color
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    //create the button
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

    //set the position of the button
    //button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 10, 50,50);
    button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 10,10);

    //set the button's title
    [button setTitle:@"Click Me!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonClick:) forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)UIControlEventTouchDown];

    //add the button to the view
    [self.view addSubview:button];  
}
```

Done, and it works, however the other 2 buttons which were added in Interface Builder have disappeared. The new button is quite small and only covers a small bit of the view.

Could anyone tell me where my buttons are going to?

Comment: the button is small because of the frame size.. try giving more width and height

Comment: If you want to large the button increase the width and length like this button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 50,50);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you allocating another view? It will replace the old one and everything it contains.
Just create the button.

Answer (score 2):

By assigning a new view - `self.view =` - you are replacing the original view set up in interface builder.  Comment out that first line and you should find the original view (and buttons) still there, with the new button added.

If you *do* want to create your view programmatically, the proper way to do it is to implement the `loadView` method and assign a new UIView to `self.view` in there. (And obviously you want to add UI items to that view.) It's worth reading `UIViewController` documentation carefully.

Here's [some example code of implementing loadView](http://chris-software.com/index.php/2009/04/29/creating-a-view-programmatically/).

Answer (score 2):

Remove two first lines and see result. There is no reason to create new whole view for viewConrtoller.

Just set frame bigger to make your new button large - `CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)`;

Answer (score 1):

Smth like this:

```
UIButton* Button = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonRoundedRect];
[Button setTitle:@"MyButton" forState:UIControlNormal];
Button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 30);
[Button addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[[self view] addSubview: Button];
```